# Persist data and pass to multiple views

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have an app where a user logs in by entering their details and that sends a HTTP GET request to my API which authenticates the user and sends the users data/user object back from the database.

Once this is done, within my HTTP request which is triggered on button tap I send the users data onto the next view and perform a transition to the view by using the following code:

```
            if let parseJSON = json
            {
                // parseJSON contains the return data. We are programmatically creating a segue between two views
               //  passing data between them.
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
                    {

                    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mainView") as! MainViewController
                    var fullname = parseJSON["employeeName"] as! String
                    var job = parseJSON["jobTitle"] as! String
                    var email = parseJSON["email"] as! String
                    vc.username = fullname
                    vc.jobTitle = job
                    vc.userEmail = email
                    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
```

The above works perfectly.The from my second view I create a prepare for segue for another view where I am trying to pass the user data that was just passed to the 2nd view when the user logged in by using the code below:

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "settings") {
        // pass data to next view
        let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SettingsTableViewController
        viewController.username = username
        viewController.jobTitle = jobTitle
    }
}
```

This again works properly. When I tap on the button to go to view 3 the prepareforsegue function passes the data and shows the following view **(ignore email field)**:

[image]

But when I click on the back button and try to access to the same view **all the data thats coming from the API and is being passed from View 1 to View 2 to View 3 disappears.** See below:

[image]

I DO understand the reason why this happening, I am passing data in 1 direction and it is not being saved only being passed from one view to another and when I go back a view that process of passing between breaks and hence the data is lost.

***My question is how can I preserve data when the user first logs in and the API sends the data back. Can I save it? and keep passing it through multiple views and still keep it no matter what?***

Any help will be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In short** : Store the data you get in an instance variable in your view and use that variable for the segues.

**Long Explanation:**
Best practice is to create a model class for the stuff you're getting from your API, put all data in a variable of that class when retrieving the info, and like a said have a variable of that type in your view classes.

Tip: read a bit about the MVC paradigma's (lotsa stuff online, if you have some time read the book Design Patterns by the gang of four)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think thats what I am doing. I am saying the data returned into a variable and passing that variable to the next view. But that still does not work, the gets lost when I click on the back button.

Comment: without knowing which are in which VC it's hard to tell where it goes wrong. But it should be preserved. NSUserDefaults is great for permanent storage if that's what you need, if not use a variable at the right place with the right scope. Anyway it would be a lot better practice to create a model, you would not have to recreate your variables again and again

Comment: I know there are probably a lot of information online but could you give me any link regarding creating models for the technique you are suggesting. That would be a great help.

Comment: MVC = Model View Control. It's a very good practice when programming, and the way iOS development was conceived uses MVC. You have to separate your data = Model from your Views (Interface Builder) and your controllers. Putting a lot of separate variables in a ViewController is not good practice. You better create a (model) class eg Person with variables: fullname, job, email,.. and then use a variable of that class in your ViewController eg: var retrievedPerson : Person. An introduction can be found : http://www.tomdalling.com/blog/software-design/model-view-controller-explained/

Comment: you'll also find the reasons there on why to do it this way and not your way. If you still need permanent persistence with NSUserDefaults you can implement it in your model (use NSData)

Comment: Glad I could help, and remember writing an app is not only about coding, but also about good design: and I don't mean UX design, I mean code design. Learn to write re-usable code, DRY code and don't forget : tests! Not only your own testing of you app but learn to use unit-testing for automated tests, it'll save you a lot of headaches in the future and a much more stable app. Read all you can about MVC and TDD (Test Driven Development)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Its very helpful. Im starting by learning how to create class models and after that I'll move on to MVC. Any suggestions for a good book for learning about clean coded app development?